# Newbie here, what exactly is acquireLock() and what's it purpose?

Tags: c++, linux, fpga

I'm relatively new to c++ and I was working on some pre-existing code that pumps some data to a FPGA on my network. I saw acquireLock() being used at the start of the code and releaseLock() being used at the end.

I was wondering what the meaning of the pair acquireLock() and releaseLock() was. Could someone please clarify and/or tell me if it has anything to do with the FPGA by any chance?

Thank you!

Comment: its is hard so say without knowing more details, but there is probably another thread that writes to the same memory location that is read when sending to the fpga. If two threads access the same memory those accesses have to be guarded by eg locking a mutex such that no two threads access the same memory at the same time

Comment: They are functions, what they do depends on their code. From their names it *sounds like* they are locking a thread's progress to stop something being accessed from more then one thread at the same time. But that's just a guess. Functions do whatever they were programmed to do and without looking at the source code of the program (or the instructions that come with it) we don't know.

Comment: btw c is not c++ and c++ is not c. Please dont use unrelated tags

Comment: hmm yeah guys that really clarified things and i think you guys are right, because my code is supposed to use the fpga for a task without interference and then leave it

Comment: FPGA and Newbie do not mix well.

Comment: Haha true trying my best here....also do you think you guys could upvote my question, new here and trying to gain some reputation

Comment: Just be thankful it hasn't been downvoted. Generally, your Q is "too broad", and has other problems. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say without actual code, but the naming suggests using [lock of some kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)), most likely to guarantee exclusive access to a resource / memory.

You can take a look at the doc page of [`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) which is a C++ 11 standard primitive which can be used to implement [mutual exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion). Its [`lock()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/lock) function should have roughly the same meaning as `acquireLock()` in your code. [`unlock()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/unlock) will be the equivalent of `releaseLock()`.

Comment: most likely its a high level wrapper for the base types

Comment: hmm yeah guys that really clarified things and i think you guys are right, because my code is supposed to use the fpga for a task without interference and then leave it